# ANDROID group buttons

Tags: android, android-layout

In main view, i have 12 buttons coming. But i will change this. I will make a pre screen. In that view, there will be 4 buttons and when clicked one of them, 3 of 12 in main view will be shown.

I dont want to make 4 views for this, seperate views. There must be a way.

**My buttons:**

```
btnUni.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.e(TAG,"ButtonUni clicked");//d.deleteOldEvents();
           // new RetrieveEvents("Uni");
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ListEvents.class);
            intent.putExtra("Type","Uni");

              //kaldırılabilir bu
            Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "LUTFEN BEKLEYINIZ... UNIVERSITE ETKINLIKLERI GOSTERILMEK ICIN HAZIRLANIYOR...",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            Log.e(TAG,"Intent created, now executing");
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    btnConcert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {//d.getAllEvents();
            Log.e(TAG,"ButtonConcert clicked");
             //new RetrieveEvents("Uni");

           Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ListEvents.class);
           intent.putExtra("Type","Concert");

            //kaldırılabilir bu
            Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "LUTFEN BEKLEYINIZ... KONSER ETKINLIKLERI GOSTERILMEK ICIN HAZIRLANIYOR...",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            Log.e(TAG,"Intent created, now executing");
           startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    btnShow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.e(TAG,"ButtonConcert clicked");
            // new RetrieveEvents("Uni");

            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ListEvents.class);
            intent.putExtra("Type","Show");

            //kaldırılabilir bu
            Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "LUTFEN BEKLEYINIZ... SHOW ETKINLIKLERI GOSTERILMEK ICIN HAZIRLANIYOR...",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            Log.e(TAG,"Intent created, now executing");
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    btnSports.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.e(TAG,"ButtonConcert clicked");
            // new RetrieveEvents("Uni");

            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ListEvents.class);
            intent.putExtra("Type","Sports");

            //kaldırılabilir bu
            Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "LUTFEN BEKLEYINIZ... Spor ETKINLIKLERI GOSTERILMEK ICIN HAZIRLANIYOR...",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            Log.e(TAG,"Intent created, now executing");
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    btnArt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.e(TAG,"ButtonConcert clicked");
            // new RetrieveEvents("Uni");

            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ListEvents.class);
            intent.putExtra("Type","Art");

            //kaldırılabilir bu
            Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "LUTFEN BEKLEYINIZ... Sergi ETKINLIKLERI GOSTERILMEK ICIN HAZIRLANIYOR...",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            Log.e(TAG,"Intent created, now executing");
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    btnTheater.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.e(TAG,"ButtonConcert clicked");
            // new RetrieveEvents("Uni");

            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ListEvents.class);
            intent.putExtra("Type","Theater");

            //kaldırılabilir bu
            Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "LUTFEN BEKLEYINIZ... TIYATRO ETKINLIKLERI GOSTERILMEK ICIN HAZIRLANIYOR...",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            Log.e(TAG,"Intent created, now executing");
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    btnExhibition.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.e(TAG,"ButtonConcert clicked");
            // new RetrieveEvents("Uni");

            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ListEvents.class);
            intent.putExtra("Type","Exhibition");

            //kaldırılabilir bu
            Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "LUTFEN BEKLEYINIZ... SERGI ETKINLIKLERI GOSTERILMEK ICIN HAZIRLANIYOR...",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            Log.e(TAG,"Intent created, now executing");
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    btnDance.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.e(TAG,"ButtonConcert clicked");
            // new RetrieveEvents("Uni");

            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ListEvents.class);
            intent.putExtra("Type","Dance");

            //kaldırılabilir bu
            Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "LUTFEN BEKLEYINIZ...  Bale ETKINLIKLERI GOSTERILMEK ICIN HAZIRLANIYOR...",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            Log.e(TAG,"Intent created, now executing");
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    btnKid.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.e(TAG,"ButtonConcert clicked");
            // new RetrieveEvents("Uni");

            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ListEvents.class);
            intent.putExtra("Type","Kid");

            //kaldırılabilir bu
            Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "LUTFEN BEKLEYINIZ... Cocuk ETKINLIKLERI GOSTERILMEK ICIN HAZIRLANIYOR...",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            Log.e(TAG,"Intent created, now executing");
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    btnCourse.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.e(TAG,"ButtonConcert clicked");
            // new RetrieveEvents("Uni");

            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ListEvents.class);
            intent.putExtra("Type","Course");

            //kaldırılabilir bu
            Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "LUTFEN BEKLEYINIZ... KURS  ETKINLIKLERI GOSTERILMEK ICIN HAZIRLANIYOR...",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            Log.e(TAG,"Intent created, now executing");
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    btnFamily.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.e(TAG,"ButtonConcert clicked");
            // new RetrieveEvents("Uni");

            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ListEvents.class);
            intent.putExtra("Type","Family");

            //kaldırılabilir bu
            Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "LUTFEN BEKLEYINIZ... AILE ETKINLIKLERI GOSTERILMEK ICIN HAZIRLANIYOR...",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            Log.e(TAG,"Intent created, now executing");
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    btnRace.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.e(TAG,"ButtonConcert clicked");
            // new RetrieveEvents("Uni");

            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ListEvents.class);
            intent.putExtra("Type","Race");

            //kaldırılabilir bu
            Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "LUTFEN BEKLEYINIZ... YARISMA  ETKINLIKLERI GOSTERILMEK ICIN HAZIRLANIYOR...",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            Log.e(TAG,"Intent created, now executing");
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

**their layout:**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="cursedchico.showmeevets.MainActivity">

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="UNIVERSITE"
    android:id="@+id/btn_uni"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="GUNCELLE"
    android:id="@+id/btn_update_db"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="En son guncelleme:"
    android:id="@+id/txt_update_time_label"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btn_update_db"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="85dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="85dp"
    android:textColor="#bf0d0d"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btn_update_db" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="Small Text"
    android:id="@+id/txt_update_time_show"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/txt_update_time_label"
    android:textColor="#3448ca" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="KONSER"
    android:id="@+id/btn_concert"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TIYATRO"
    android:id="@+id/btn_theater"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btn_uni"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="SHOW"
    android:id="@+id/btn_show"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btn_concert"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btn_concert"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/btn_concert" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="SPOR"
    android:id="@+id/btn_sports"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btn_theater"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="SERGI"
    android:id="@+id/btn_art"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btn_show"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="FUAR"
    android:id="@+id/btn_exhibition"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btn_sports"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="DANS"
    android:id="@+id/btn_dance"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btn_exhibition"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="COCUK"
    android:id="@+id/btn_kid"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btn_dance"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="KURS"
    android:id="@+id/btn_course"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btn_race"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="AILE"
    android:id="@+id/btn_family"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btn_art"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="YARISMA"
    android:id="@+id/btn_race"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btn_family"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
```

For example there will be `art` in pre screen. When clicked, art theater exhibition buttons will be shown.

Answer (score 0):

Group your 12 buttons in four separate layouts, set visibility of these layouts onclick of previous screen buttons.

Answer (score 0):

try this method, in your xml file update this button

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="UNIVERSITE"
    android:id="@+id/btn_uni"
    android:onClick="btn_uni"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

In Java file use the onclick method as
no need of initialization,

```
public void btn_uni(view View){
   // your code goes here
}
```